# 422 when posting file with requests

Tags: python, api, curl, request

So I've been trying to figure this out all day but haven't been able to make any progress.  I have this curl command, which works:

```
curl -X POST -H "x-hermes-key: <KEY>" -H "Accept: application/json"  --form file='@example_files/ex1.pdf' <URL> -kv
```

When I try to run its equivalent in python with requests, I get a 422 error:

```
header = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Hermes-Key": <KEY>
        }

f = {'file': open("example_files/ex1.pdf", "rb")}
r_create = requests.post(url=<URL>, headers=header, files=f)
```

Can anyone help me see where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Try this: *with open('example_files/ex1.pdf', 'rb') as f: requests.post(url=url, headers=header, data=f)*

Comment: `f['file']` must be a tuple, I guess. See [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/).

Comment: @CodeMonkey It then gives a decode error, also tried it with files=f

Comment: @rv.kvetch Its defined above, I'll edit my post to include it

Comment: @rv.kvetch Tried that as well, no luck

Comment: Postman's code snippet gives: files=[
  ('file',('file',open('/path/to/file','rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
]

Comment: What effect does `--form` have on the curl command?  And are you doing that same thing in the python code?

Comment: @kgiannakakis That returns a 500 error

Comment: @JohnGordon That I'm not so sure of and is perhaps the root of the problem? I did not write the curl command, so I don't know what it is or how to replicate it in python. When using the curlconverter.com, it seems to ignore it

Comment: Is there no error message associated with the errors? `print(r_create.content)`...

Comment: @AKX It is a very helpful "Failed to create"

Comment: Yeah, that's not very helpful. Well, what about any documentation for the system, whatever it is you're trying to access..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should match the curl command and POST with content-type=multipart/form-data.

You can set the filename, content_type, and headers explicitly in a tuple for the 'file' value.

```python
headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Hermes-Key": <KEY>
        }

url = <URL>

files = [('file', ('ex1.pdf', open('example_files/ex1.pdf', 'rb'),
                     'application/octet-stream'))]
r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, files=files)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: This was almost it! Just replacing 'upload' with 'file' solved it, thank you so much!